# boost::asio::async_read get end of file error

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio

I've written a program which uses boost:asio library, which transfers data between 2 tcp servers.
One server uses the following code to send data:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> s =
  std::make_shared<std::string>(message);
boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(*s),
  std::bind(&TcpServer::HandleWrite, shared_from_this(), s, _1, _2));
```

In another TcpServer, when I use async_read_until to get data, everything works fine, but if I replace async_read_until to async_read, it gives an `End Of File` error:

```
boost::asio::streambuf input_buffer;
boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, input_buffer, match_condition(),
  std::bind(&TcpServer::HandleRead, shared_from_this(), _1));
//boost::asio::async_read(socket_, input_buffer, boost::asio::transfer_all(),
//  std::bind(&TcpServer::HandleRead, shared_from_this(), _1));
```

If I use `boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1)` in async_read, I can get the expected result.

Why did this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An eof error indicates that the writer side closed the connection. Any data sent before that should still be available in the `TcpServer::HandleRead` callback. Check the `bytes_transferred` parameter to find out how much data was received by the reader.

Comment: I've find the reason, if I use transfer_all, I need use a buffer with fixed size or the error will occured because async_read can't fullfill the buffer.

Comment: The error occurs because the end of the stream is reached (and you requested to keep reading until that event) - ie. it's not really an error in that something failed. It just indicates the end of the stream. The data is still available to you.